# Comment peut-on dire « to outstay one's welcome » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, vocabulaire

On emploie [cette expression](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outstay_one%27s_welcome) quand un invité est resté trop longtemps lors d'une fête. L'invité est utilisé comme sujet de l'expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lorsque quelqu'un reste trop longtemps on dit qu'il s'*éternise*. [Sens 3](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9terniser) du Wiktionnaire :

> Demeurer trop longtemps ; s’attarder plus qu’il ne convient.

Avec un sens plus général on dit « abuser de l'hospitalité » de quelqu'un.

Answer (score 5):

L'expression qui convient en Français est probablement *s'incruster*. "Probablement", car elle est d'un registre familier, tandis que *to outstay one's welcome* ne semble pas du tout l'être.

Ainsi :

> *Tout les monde est parti vers 1h, mais lui s'est incrusté jusqu'à 3h du matin, je n'en pouvais plus !* correspond au sens 1 du terme suivant le lien que tu nous as indiqué.

et

> *Il s'est incrusté à ma soirée ! Mais je ne l'ai jamais invité cet idiot !* correspond au sens 2 du terme suivant ce même lien.

Comment: S'incruster pour moi s'est s'inviter alors qu'on ne l'a pas été seulement (et c'est très familier), ce n'est pas vraiment le sens de l'expression anglaise.

Comment: Pour moi, le terme _s'éterniser_ est plus juste ici.

Comment: Oui, aucun doute sur le fait que c'est familier, c'est pourquoi je l'ai mentionné. J'aime beaucoup "abuser de l'hospitalité".

Quant au sens, je l'ai entendu dans les deux cas. C'est vrai que cette expression semble plus large que l'expression à traduire.